# nginx redirect mask

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm new to nginx and am trying to figure out an issue with redirection. I'm trying to redirect a website from a host running a web application to another domain. That part I've done but I'm looking to mask it. When it redirects, I don't want the user to know they've gone to another domain.

I've substituted the domain names for privacy of my client. But, they are on a Linode at test.com that's running a web application that's at sub.test.com. All I want is for any user visiting test.com to be redirected to a temporary site hosted on other.com but without exposing the domain.

Previously, someone had shown me how to do it but it was a long time ago and I no longer have the information to reference. Can someone help me out? I don't want to expose the domain of the testing environment.

```
server {
     listen       80;
     server_name  www.test.com test.com www.test.net test.net;

     rewrite      ^ http://other.com/sub redirect;

     location / {
         root     /srv/http/www.test.com;
         index    index.html;
     }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please note that tags aren't keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your post doesn't help categorize it.  Tags also stand alone, meaning that combining `web` and `server` does not mean you are talking about web servers.  Please be sure to select your tags with care.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that with *redirect*, cause redirect is actually like telling the browser where to fetch page from, so you can't obscure the real location. 
I guess what you need is *proxying*, e.g. a client requests some document from your server (test.com), then your server fetches the document from some other server (other.com) and returns that document to a client as if it was generated on test.com - it that case a client won't be able to determine where actually the document is originating from.

This can be done with:

```
server_name test.com;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://other.com;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the redirect to not change the user-visible domain name then you need to change it from a 301 to a 302 by changing your rewrite as follows:

```
rewrite ^ http://other.com/sub redirect;
```

Comment: It's giving me an error saying that there are too many redirect requests. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting? Sounds like you're ending up in some kind of redirect loop, though since you're redirecting to some other server that's puzzling.

Comment: btw since you're rewriting everything (`^` regex matches everything) to the other server you can leave out the `location /`-block entirely it's unnecessary

Comment: It's odd because in Chrome it redirects fine but without masking but in Safari i get "Too many redirects occurred trying to open "www.test.com/";. This might occur if you open a page that is redirected to open another page which is then redirected to open the original page.

Comment: are there any redirects in your other.com config?

Comment: There is not. I figured it out doing it the simple way and just putting the temp page in srv/http and having it pull locally. Figured that's the best way anyhow. Also, I found out there was a frame that was messing with the redirection. Thanks for your help!